# Concise yet geometric algebraic topology book/resource

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, book-recommendation, geometric-topology

I am looking for a book(or any other resource) that perhaps is like Hatcher(geometric, visual, and intuitive) but perhaps less chatty.

I have tried to read through May's book, but it is kinda the polar opposite of Hatcher in terms of length and viewpoint(mainly algebraic and ~200 pages).

Is such a compromise between a geometric/visual viewpoint and concision even possible? Or is Hatcher(or something else) the only way?

Please note that the "contents" of algebraic topology that I am looking for are the standard topics normally covered in graduate algebraic topology, which would probably be the same contents of Hatcher due to its popularity.

I found Bott-Tu which is really interesting, but it is quite non-standard and feels more like a supplement to a main text/resource.

My background in general topology is Jänich's book and Hatchers point-set topology notes, and my algebra background is everything up to Galois Theory and the basics of category theory.

Thank you all very much!

Comment: Soryy but what is wrong with Hatcher's algebraic topology book?

Comment: And exactly what topic's book are you looking for? Differential topology, algbraic topology, 3 manifold, 4 manifold, geometry-topology-- What exactly?

Comment: I find hatcher to be too wordy

Comment: wait, what do you mean by too wordy?

Comment: wordy as in taking up a lot of words to explain things, etc. this isn't necessarily a bad thing, it's just that I would prefer a more concise exposition. At the same time, I really like the visual/geometric nature of hatcher's book, so my question asks if there exists a resource that is both geometric/visual and concise. Perhaps I should add this to the question if it causes confusion.

Comment: @HamuraOtsutsuki Do you know Bredon's Topology and Geometry?

Comment: @AloizioMacedo I think I've heard of it before. How well does it satisfy my criteria?

Comment: @HamuraOtsutsuki Well, it depends. It is reasonably concise, definitely less wordy than Hatcher, and I think it is fairly geometric. But perceptions may vary. Nevertheless, it may be worth it to check it out.

Comment: You have to be "chatty" to explain the intuition.